# Make apt ignore a single recommendation

Tags: apt, dependencies, owncloud

I'm looking to install owncloud, which has this recommendation line:

```
Recommends: curl, exim4 | mail-transport-agent, php5-imagick, php5-apc, libreoffice-writer
```

I want to install all of the requirements except for `libreoffice-writer`.
I know I can ignore *all* recommendations using `--no-install-recommends`, but is there any way to specifically ignore *one* recommendation?

**Edit:**
I want to automate it, so solutions manually deslecting libreoffice using aptitude etc. aren't that useful

Answer (score 2):

Install `vim`:

```sh
sudo apt install vim
```

Install `vim` without recommends:

```sh
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends vim
```

Install `vim` with recommends except `xz-utils`:

```sh
sudo apt install vim xz-utils-
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want to automate it, I'm assuming you mean you wish to install `owncloud` on many machines but never install `libreoffice-writer` (and all its dependencies).

If that's the case, then you want to make use of [Apt Pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences). This lets you specify specific versions of packages, including no version at all.

Per this [question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75895/how-to-forbid-a-specific-package-to-be-installed) the way to do this is to add the following to `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: libreoffice-writer
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

If you need to do this totally automatically (such as in a single ssh command) you could just echo that into the file before doing the install. That'd look something like this:

```
echo 'Package: libreoffice-writer\nPin: origin ""\nPin-Priority: -1' >> /etc/apt/preferences && apt-get install owncloud
```